# How to merge two two dimensional arrays with the same number of elements per sub array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I need to merge the second array into the first. For example the first array is

```
$data_array = array
(
array('Ford','Escape','25000','new')
);
```

The second array is

```
$new_array = array
(
array('Toyota','Camry','12000','used')
);
```

For merging the two arrays I tried

```
$data_array = array_merge($data_array[0],$new_array[0]);
print_r($data_array);
```

This combines the two arrays into one row array. What I want is to create two rows, each containing one of those arrays.

Sample result:

```
array(array('Ford','Escape','25000','new'),array('Toyota','Camry','12000','used'))
```

Comment: `array_merge` doesn't perform in place operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to assign the merged result. Pay attention to the function signature and description in the manual for [array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php):

> Merges the elements of one or more arrays together so that the values of one are appended to the end of the previous one. **It returns the resulting array**.

```
$merged_array = array_merge($data_array[0],$new_array[0]);
print_r($merged_array);
```

You could call it `$data_array` and overwrite the existing one:

```
$data_array = array_merge($data_array[0],$new_array[0]);
print_r($data_array);
```

Or even `$data_array[0]`:

```
$data_array[0] = array_merge($data_array[0],$new_array[0]);
print_r($data_array);
```

Contrast this with something like [sort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php):

```
bool sort ( array &$array [, int $sort_flags = SORT_REGULAR ] )
```

Where the `bool` means that it returns `true` or `false` and the `&` preceding `$array` means that the array is passed by reference and modified.

However, after your edit it seems that you want the two rows in your original arrays to be two rows in a new array, so just don't specify the index `[0]`:

```
$data_array = array_merge($data_array,$new_array);
print_r($data_array);
```

Comment: This adds the elements in the new array to the end of the old array. It doesn't make them into two array rows belonging to one multidimensional array, which is what I want.

Comment: Then you need to give an example of what you want the result to look like.

Comment: Edited at the bottom.